# Getting a value of a site

Tags: php

So as the title says I want to get a value of this site : [Xtremetop100 Conquer-Online](http://xtremetop100.com/conquer-online)

My server is called Zath-Co and right now we are on rank 11.
What I want is that a script is going to tell me which rank we are, how much in's and out's we have. Only thing is we are getting up and down in the list so I want a script that checks on the name not at the rank, but I can't come out of it.
I tried this script

```
  <?php $lines = file('http://xtremetop100.com/conquer-online');
  while ($line = array_shift($lines)) {
  if (strpos($line, 'Zath-Co') !== false) break; }
  print_r(explode(" ", $line)); ?>
```

But it is only showing the name of my server and the description.
How can I get this to work as I want or do I have to use something really different. (If yes then what to use, and a example would be great.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can also be fixed with the file()-function, as you tried yourself. You just have to look up the source code and find the starting-line of your "part". I found out (in the source-code), that you need 7 lines to get the rank, description and in/out data. Here is a tested example:

```
<?php 

$lines = file('http://xtremetop100.com/conquer-online');
$CountLines = sizeof( $lines);
$arrHtml = array();
for( $i = 0; $i < $CountLines; $i++) {
    if( strpos( $lines[$i], '/sitedetails-1132314895')) {
        //The seven lines taken here under is your section at the site
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++]; 
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        $arrHtml[] = $lines[$i++];
        break;
    }
}

//We simply strip all tags, so you just got the content.
$arrHtml = array_map("strip_tags", $arrHtml);

//Here we echo the data
echo implode('<br>',$arrHtml);

?>
```

You can fix the layout yourself by taking out each element from the $arrHtml throug a loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is exactly what I wanted. Where can I contact you?

Comment: No problem, I am glad you can use itfor your purpose. You can contact me on mail for further questions - hskrijelj@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SimpleXML and XPath. Here is working example:

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://xtremetop100.com/conquer-online');

// suppress invalid markup warnings
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

// Create SimpleXML object
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->strictErrorChecking = false;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);

$xpath = '//span[@class="hd1" and ./a[contains(., "Zath-Co")]]/ancestor::tr/td[@class="number" or @class="stats1" or @class="stats"]';
$anchor = $xml->xpath($xpath);

// Clear invalid markup error buffer
libxml_clear_errors();

$rank = (string)$anchor[0]->b;
$in   = (string)$anchor[1]->span;
$out  = (string)$anchor[2]->span;

// Clear invalid markup error buffer
libxml_clear_errors();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.
But how can I let it show the in's and out's too?